# How display if a checked box is checked and still receive input with ngmodel from the check box

Tags: angular, ionic2

Am trying to display if a checkbox is checked or not and still send input from the checkbox using `ngModel` in ionic 2, below is my code.

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <ion-checkbox color="primary" checked="{{property.alarmSystem}}" [(ngModel)]="store.checked"></ion-checkbox><p>Pantry / Store</p>
</div><!-- /.checkbox-->
```

It doesn't display anything even when the value of the checkbox is suppose to be true but when I remove the `[(ngmodel)]` everything is fine. Please what is my mistake?

Comment: hello minte,
i think you need to remove "{{ }}" from checked

Comment: <ion-checkbox color="primary" checked="property.alarmSystem" [(ngModel)]="store.checked"></ion-checkbox><p>Pantry / Store</p>

Try this one